# Error login_required django

Tags: django, decorator, login-control

How to Handle this error message when a user tries to enter a page without login?
Actually I need to return the error page to avoid the 404 error.

Look what I tried:

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/protected_message/')
def my_protected_view(request):
    """A view that can only be accessed by logged-in users"""
    return render(request, 'bands/protected.html', {'current_user': request.user})
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^protected/$', 'mysite.bands.views.my_protected_view'),
    url(r'^protected_message/?next=/protected/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

I read it all, but I could not "fix" the mess.

[login-required-decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)
[auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: Maybe you can write your own `login_required` decorator to override the former one, and add redirect on the decorator function to an error page.

Comment: To start with, you don't put query strings inside URL patterns. Remove all this `?next=/protected/` from your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in a simple way, I do not know if it's the most efficient, but it worked.

views

```
def protected_message(request):
    return render(request, 'bands/protected_message.html')
```

url

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'protected_message'),
```

menu template

```
<li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Login</a></li>
```

protected_message.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Protected</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Access denied</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to call `login_required` is enough.

Two methods

1. In your settings.py file include this `LOGIN_URL = 'login_url'`
2. And another one method is

   ```
   @login_required(login_url='/login_url/')
   def my_protected_view(request):
   ```

Custom error message

```
def profile_required(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs) :
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Error Message')
    return inner
```